# How to change property of control in master page from child form in asp.net

Tags: css, asp.net, master-pages, parent-child

Am developing a vertical navigation web application. When I click on hyperlink(present in master page), the child .aspx page loads, but since it is a new page load, the default color of hyperlink is set. I want to set a different color to the hyperlink of the corresponding page loaded.

Master page code:

```
<header id="leftpanel">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li><br />
        <li><a href="Default2.aspx">About Us</a></li><br />
        <li><a href="Default3.aspx">Tourism</a></li><br />
        <li><a href="Default4.aspx">Enquiry</a></li><br />
    </ul>
</header>

    <div id="mainpanel"> 
        <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text="MAIN TITLE"></asp:Label>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
```

CSS of the code:

```
body {
  top:0;
  left:0;
  margin:0;
}

#leftpanel{
 position:fixed;
 left:0;
 width:25%;
 float: left;
 height:100%;
 background-color: gray;
 text-align:center;
 padding-top:250px;
}
ul, li{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 list-style:none;
}

#leftpanel ul li{
 font-size:15px;
 line-height:15px;
 letter-spacing:3px;
 color:white;
 margin-bottom:20px;
 -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
 -webkit-transition:color 0.3s ease-out;
 font: 20px/1.4em "PT Sans Narrow", "Arial", sans-serif;
}

#leftpanel ul li a{
 color:white;
 -webkit-transition:color 0.3s ease-out;
 -moz-transition:color 0.3s ease-out;
 -o-transition:color 0.3s ease-out;
 -ms-transition: color 0.3s ease-out;
 transition:color 0.3s ease-out;
 font-weight:bold;
 text-decoration:none;
 background-color:gray;
 cursor:pointer;
}

#leftpanel ul li:hover, #leftpanel ul li a:hover , #leftpanel ul li.current{
 color:#0fe9bd;
 -webkit-transition:color 0.3s ease-out;
 -moz-transition:color 0.3s ease-out;
 -o-transition:color 0.3s ease-out;
 -ms-transition: color 0.3s ease-out;
 transition:color 0.3s ease-out;
 cursor:pointer;
}  

#leftpanel a:hover, #leftpanel .active{
 color:#0fe9bd;
 font:x-large
}

#mainpanel{
 position:fixed;
 width:75%;
 float:left;
 left:25%;
 height:100%;
 text-align:center;
 align-items:center;
 background-color:#0fe9bd;
 color:black;
 font-weight:bold;
 font: 20px/1.4em "PT Sans Narrow", "Arial", sans-serif;
}
```

Also, If i place an update panel in the content place holder of the master page, how to load the child pages into the update panel on click of hyperlink, instead of re loading the entire page?

Comment: are you able to use ajax at all?

Comment: @jbutler483: I did not get a chance to do it. But, the page seems to open fine without any error.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `li` or `a` server side then find on child page and set the back color

Master page code:

```
<header id="leftpanel">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Default.aspx" id="home" runat="server">Home</a></li><br />
        <li><a href="Default2.aspx">About Us</a></li><br />
        <li><a href="Default3.aspx">Tourism</a></li><br />
        <li><a href="Default4.aspx">Enquiry</a></li><br />
    </ul>
</header>

    <div id="mainpanel"> 
        <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text="MAIN TITLE"></asp:Label>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
```

Child page code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    HtmlAnchor b = (HtmlAnchor)this.Page.Master.FindControl("home");
                b.Attributes["class"] = "active";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `a:active and a:visited`
If you want the link corresponding to current page to be highlighted then

> `.currentPage {
>   color: Aqua;
>    background-color: #000000;
>   }`

Add this class to corresponding `<li>`.
Hope this will help you..